# The equation $x^2 = 2$ has $4$ different solutions in a commutative ring with unity ($1 \neq 0$). Show that in this ring $\exists$ zero divisor.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> The equation $x^2 = 2$ has $4$ different solutions in a commutative
>   ring with unity ($1 \neq 0$). Show that in this ring $\exists$ zero
>   divisor.

Any help would be appreciate.

I'm only have the following:

- A zero divisor is an element $a \in R\ \text{if}\ \exists b\in R, b \neq 0: ab = 0$.
- Well, the equation of the problem can be written as $x^2 -2 = 0
     \implies (x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})=0$

I'm beginning with ring so I'm clueless here. Aside of the question above, how does it possible for $x^2 = 2$ to have $4$ solutions instead of (the known/obvious) two?

Comment: Your definition of zero divisor is not correct.

Comment: Might help if you specify the book you are using, if there is not a book then a link to your lecture notes.

Comment: @JJR Hopefully now it's correct.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm using a textbook, but I'm translating from russian. I mean, there is no english version.

Comment: @Jazz yes now it's correct :)

Comment: Hint: if $a^2=2$ and $b^2=2$ then $a^2-b^2=0\,$. Since the ring is commutative, $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\,$.

Comment: Jazz, understood., thank you. A book or notes give us a better idea of what you have been studying just before getting to your question. An alternative would be for you to summarize what you have been doing, recent theorems proved. On this site that is usually called "context."

Answer (score 5):

Here's the intuition.  You might expect to be able to factor $x^2-2$ as $(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})$.  If your ring has no zero divisors, the only way a product can be $0$ is if one of the factors is $0$, so the only way $x^2-2$ can be $0$ is if $x-\sqrt{2}=0$ or $x+\sqrt{2}=0$.  That is, the only possible solutions to $x^2=2$ are $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{2}$.  So there can be at most two solutions.

Now to be clear, this argument is nonsense as written.  The symbol $\sqrt{2}$ has no meaning in a general commutative ring.  To make the argument rigorous, you might let $a$ be one of the solutions to $x^2=2$, so you can think of $a$ as a square root of $2$.  Then if you can prove that $x^2-2=(x-a)(x+a)$ for all $x\in R$, the argument goes through.  I'll leave verifying the details to you.

As an example for how $x^2=2$ can have more than two solutions, consider the ring $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.  The element $2$ of this ring is the ordered pair $(2,2)$ (since $2$ really means the sum of two copies of the multiplicative identity, and the multiplicative identity is $(1,1)$).  This has four different square roots: $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}),(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}),(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}),$ and $(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

For example in the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/119\mathbb{Z}$ you have $11^2 = 121 \equiv 2 \pmod {119}$ and hence $(-11)^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {119}$. But you also have $45^2 = 2025 = 17 \cdot 121 + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod {119}$. Thus you have 4 solutions to $x^2 = 2$: $11, 45, 74 (= -45)$ and $108 (= -11)$.

One way to do this is to note that if $R$ has no zero divisors, then we can form the fraction field $\mathbb{Q}(R)$ and in fields, there can only be two solutions to $x^2 = 2$ (polynomials of degree $n$ have at most $n$ roots in fields).

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be solution of equation $x^2=2$ then $-a$ is also solution. Since there are 4 solutions then there is $b\ne\pm a$ s.t. $b^2=2$. Then $0=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and $a\pm b\ne 0.$